# Application Icon Ordering in Main Menu

Tags: nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop

I have Android Lollipop 5.1 running on my Nexus 5 phone. Whenever I install or uninstall an application, the order of all the app icons is re-sorted in alphabetical order. Is there any way in which we can configure this ordering mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the default app drawer on the Nexus 5 always sorts the applications in alphabetical order only. So if you would want to order them in a different manner, you would have to use a 3rd Party launcher app(Go Launcher, Aviate etc.)

Here is a link to 3rd party launchers that are available on the Play Store: 
[3rd party Launchers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Launcher&c=apps)